# Oracle Enterprise Manager 13c - query used in metric

Tags: oracle, jobs, oracle-enterprise-manager

I got task - **"send me the query used in this metric?"**

It is related to Job with status "FAILED".

I find this failed Job but can't find with which query this metric detect this error.

Comment: Not sure if this [helps](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/cloud-control-13.3/EMVWS/EMVWS.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I already find something in documentation. "mgmt$annotations" view could help to identify.
But it is not clearly how to check via OEM console for queries which use in metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 months of SR to Oracle started we finally get one-off patch for this issue.
Oracle recognized it as official bug.
Patch number is 33074193: Jobs stuck in scheduled status after RU9 applied on OMS